# updating cordova 2.3 in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, cordova

can someone tell me how I can update the cordova 2.3 in eclipse?
I installed from (Help / Install new software / add) and put the following address (http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2/download/) but now the version 2.3 is available and I don't know how updated it.

Anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the latest version of PhoneGap is not shipped as an Eclipse plugin.

If you have an existing project and want to upgrade it, you can take a look at PhoneGap's [upgrading guides](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_upgrading_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Guides) which have step by step instructions